# How to add, remove and change glyphs in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, editor, monaco-editor

I am able to add glyph to the editor but I am not able to **remove** and **edit** the glyph. Can you please give me the right way of doing it.

```
<h2>Monaco Editor Sample</h2>
<div id="container" style="width:80%;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>

<!-- OR ANY OTHER AMD LOADER HERE INSTEAD OF loader.js -->
<script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    var editor,decorations;
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
         editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: [
                'function x() {',
                '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                '}',
            ].join('\n'),
            language: 'javascript',
            theme: "myCustomTheme",
            automaticLayout: true,
            readOnly: false,
            mouseWheelZoom:true,
            glyphMargin:true,
            fontSize:'20px'
        });
   //below is the glyph I am calling
    var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [     
    {
        range: new monaco.Range(3,1,3,1),
        options: {
            isWholeLine: true,
            className: 'myContentClass',
            glyphMarginClassName: 'glyph-error',
        }
    }
    ]);
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to delete or modify the range and style of the glyph using **decorations** variable but it is a string object.

This is the how my editor looks with a squared glyph:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of `deltaDecorations` is an array of strings. Each string is an identifier of a decoration that was created by the last `deltaDecorations` call.

To modify an existing decoration you must *replace* it with a new one as shown below.

```js
var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [     
    {
        range: new monaco.Range(3,1,3,1),
        options: {
            isWholeLine: true,
            className: 'myContentClass',
            glyphMarginClassName: 'glyph-error',
        }
    }
]);

// Now move the previously created decoration to line 2
var targetId = decorations[0];
editor.deltaDecorations([targetId], [     
    {
        range: new monaco.Range(2,1,2,1),
        options: {
            isWholeLine: true,
            className: 'myContentClass',
            glyphMarginClassName: 'glyph-error',
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: is there any way to add icon in the glyph margin hover message?

Comment: That's a separate question you should ask on your own. But yes, you can have icons there too, but via CSS, not via a Monaco API.

Comment: Hi, I know this is unrelated but can you guide me on how I can set `classname` to few lines which are not continuous?

Comment: @MiKr13 I think the only way is to create separate decorations. E.g. create a decoration for each continuous range or create a decoration for each line.

Comment: @ArturKovacs Thanks for quick reply. I feel like I should explain my use-case first. I was trying to create an editor where some code will be uneditable while other lines will be editable. So I thought I should add className to the line itself & then use CSS to avoid pointer events & cursor. Unfortunately, it still allows you to click on the lines which aren't supposed to be editable. I can handle it with JS but I don't want that line to be clickable or changeable at all. And that's where I've been stuck. I can apply the `className` but it still allows clicks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how that could be done.

Comment: Wow, what a horrible API! Also this method is unfortunately deprecated, and it doesn't look like it's possible to remove decorations anymore. `createDecorationsCollection` has no way to do this.